# WinGrid creating a default row when collection is zero

Tags: infragistics

*(Before I continue, I have posted this question on the Infragistics forum too, so if I have broke any rules by posting on here also, I will happily remove it, but as Stackoverflow is so popular for us developers, it makes sense to also post it on here...)*

When having no data in my own IBind collection on form load, I bind the collection using the function wingrid.SetDataBinding(collection, null, true); via the run-time. However, the collection then comes back with having an object in it ( therefore the count = 1) and therefore a blank row is created.

is there a way for the grid from preventing this behaviour when the collection is 0 before the bind?

Note: When there is data before the bind. i.e. data from the back-end..the grid works perfectly by only creating 1 row per object inside the collection, but if there is no data from the backend, the above happens.

Thanks

Chris

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.infragistics.com/community/forums/t/87478.aspx

The problem is to do with the 1.1 Framework, if you are using 2 or above, the problem shouldn't occur.